# How to apply a brute force approach to solve Missionaries and Cannibals problem?

Tags: python, recursion, artificial-intelligence, brute-force

I am attempting a brute force ([generate and test](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-and-test-search/)) approach to solve the [Missionaries and Cannibals problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missionaries_and_cannibals_problem).

I have this list of tuples, which represents the actions to perform on a given state:

```
# [(take one missionary, take no cannibals), (take no cannibals, take one missionary), etc]
actions = [(1, 0) (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (0, 2)]
```

I have this starting state:

```
# 3 cannibals and missionaries on the left side
initial_state = [3, 3, 0, 0, Left]
```

I have this goal state:

```
 # 3 cannibals and missionaries on the right side
goal_state= [0, 0, 3, 3, Right]
```

I wrote the following functions to generate states and test the validity of each generated state:

```
def valid_state(a_state):
    if (a_state[1] >= 0 and a_state[0] >= 0) and not (
            do_cannibals_outnumber_missionaries(a_state[0], a_state[1])):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def generate_states():
    for i in moves:
        a_state = [init_state[0] - i[0],
                   init_state[1] - i[1],
                   init_state[2] + i[0],
                   init_state[3] + i[1],
                   not init_state[4]] #cross to right side of river

        if valid_state(a_state):   #this weeds out invalid states
            visited.append(a_state)   #this list contains all the visited, valid states
```

When I run my code with the initial state, I get:

```
[[3, 2, 0, 1, Right], [2, 2, 1, 1, Right], [3, 1, 0, 2, Right]]
```

How do I apply this same logic to generate more states out of these ones (i.e. take missionaries and cannibals to left side and store the next series of valid state- so on until I reach the goal state)?

I feel like this could work with recursion... I'm not looking for a highly optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

The general form of a recursive program to find all solutions will look like:

```
all_paths = []
def move_boat(state, history=None):
    if history is None:
        history = []
    # if len(history) > 50: return
    if is_final_state(state):  # are we finished?
        all_paths.append(history + [state])
    else:
        for new_state in generate_next_states(state, actions):  # generate all possible next states
            if not is_legal_state(new_state):
                continue
            move_boat(new_state, history + [state])
```

since it's possible to get into an infinite loop by generate moves that move the same person back-and-forth, you should probably have some safety check like the commented-out if statement.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. Am I correct in thinking generate_next_states(state, actions) returns a LIST of valid next states?

Comment: yes, or all possible next states based on `actions`.